# UITabBarController: Thread 1: Signal SIGABRT

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, xcode7

I have a UITabBarController set up to four different views. [image: Like this]

The first two and last tab bar items properly segue to the proper scene. However, when I click on the "search" tab bar item, the app freezes and gives me an error of Thread 1: Signal SIGABRT. The segue seems to be exactly similar to the other ones so I'm confused. The search page uses a navigation controller.

2[image]3[image]4[image]5[image]

When I checked other similar questions, the usual solution was to find any missing or extra outlets. But I didn't find any or see any yellow triangles.

I redid the segue, deleted the derived data, cleaned and rebuilt, and reset the simulator with no luck. Does anybody know how to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check the ViewController associated with that tab.  It's probably pointing to something that doesnt exist.

Comment: Check the debug console. If you scroll up past all the numbers, it should give you a short message about what error was thrown. If you can't understand it, you should also post the debug console so we can help you.

Comment: Add a break point in viewDidLoad of newly presented view controller. So if that breakpoint is hit, its not issue with segue but with some UI element in the new controller. And as said by @orccrusher99 post error message from error log.